# Tensorflow: Getting a high loss in Trainingsmodel and how Train a CSV data with LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Im trying to train my CSV Data to make prediction. Im using Tensorflow to train the data. But at some point im getting a high loss in my trainingsdata and my `categorical_accuracy` has the same value.

1. What is wrong in my code?
2. How can i overcome this to reduce my loss?
3. I would like to train these with LSTM, since its one of the best models exploited to predict. How can i implement this in a code?

Im using Tensorflow for the the first time and do not know how to do it properly. I hope to receive your support.

This is what the content of my CSV file looks like:

```
class    x1        y1     ...     y21       z21 
A     0.187087  0.668525  ... -0.024700  0.220235 
B     0.202503  0.669253  ... -0.107100  0.240229 
....
C     0.248009  0.676325  ... -0.070317  0.278087  
C     0.245750  0.658381  ... -0.077429  0.282217 
D     0.235889  0.643202  ... -0.080697  0.262705
....
```

My Trainings Epoche from my Python Console, where my loss ist really high:

```
Epoch 340/500
1132/1132 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 7.7938e-04 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0561
Epoch 341/500
1132/1132 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 9.2271e-06 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0561
```

Comment: It is very low actually, 9.2271e-06 = 0.0000092271. That being said, your metric should be `sparse_categorical_accuracy`.

Comment: Should `loss` then also be `sparse_categorical_accuracy`? Or which loss would you make then?

Comment: @Mayama: Your loss function is ok. and as Frightera said, your loss values are very low, and you really don't need to reduce your loss. Jus change `metrics`. And for LSTM you should convert your tabular data to timeseries. In other words, add a new dimension called timesteps. Then you can feed them to LSTM layers.

Comment: Your new edit completely broke the comments. Now your model is not correct as `softmax` with 1 neuron will only produce a constant output.

Comment: Could you provide some code of your model so that we can look into it to identify the issue. Thanks